# White screen after edit/post comment in iOS SO/SE app

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

Ever since I upgraded to iOS 11.2 beta, both my Stack Overflow application and the Stack Exchange application shared the same problem. Every time I post a comment or edit an existing comment, it will say "success" and stuck on a blank screen.

Although this might not be a *major* issue, it annoys me quite a lot, since I post many comments and it's frustrating to always have to exit the page after posting a comment. (*edit:* this problem also occurs when deleting your own comment, and deleting a not-yet finished writing comment)

Here is a cross-site dupe, and that question confirms the problem existing in the SE app, while I'm confirming it's occurring in *both* the SO and SE app:
[Screen goes white when posting a comment (iOS 11.2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302840/353919)

---

In the SE app:

[image: SE app]

---

In the SO app:

[image: SO app]

- App Version: The newest version of both SO and SE app (As of January 29, 2018, SO V1.0.1 and SE V1.6.6.2)
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 11.2 (Build 15C5107a)
- OS Version: Version 11.3 (Build 15E5167f)

Comment: This has been bugging me like nobody’s business for a while now, too. If only there were still some kind of manpower devoted to developing the apps, instead of just leaving them to languish and become increasingly unusable. :-(

Comment: This bug's still there, even though we should've passed the 6-8 weeks mark by now...

Comment: A workaround in the StackOverflow version only is to rotate the device between landscape and portrait layouts.