# Pasting into a comment field fails in the Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: bug, comments, editor, ios-app, comment-edits

In the [Stack Overflow app for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808) devices, on my iPhone 5S at least, pasting copied text into the editing field when posting a comment does nothing.

This failure happens usually, if not always (I cannot remember when it last worked). This has been a problem for at least several months, maybe a year.

I tried deleting the app from my phone and reinstalling, but the problem remains. I have been through many updates to iOS from Apple, but the problem remains.

Pasting into an answer always works. Only pasting into a comment is a problem.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 5s (GSM)
- OS Version: Version 12.1.3 (Build 16D39)

Comment: Cut, copy and paste has been broken on the iOS app for ages.

Comment: The Stack Exchange apps are in a sorry state. Pasting doesn't work, and if you write a comment and submit, you are likely to end up with a black view (you can go back a step, but the question is no longer visible).

Comment: Cross-site related on MSE (since 2017, for SE App instead of SO App): [iOS 11-12 - unable to paste into comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299803)

Comment: @MartijnPieters So true. Found this existing Meta Question about the blank screen: [*White screen after edit/post comment in iOS SO/SE app*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359318/642706)

Comment: Note that development on both the SO and the SE app has stopped. It's unlikely this will get fixed. For Android, the Stack Overflow app has been removed from the store. [Meta thread about development stopping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/369403) and [one about it not resuming anytime soon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317707/369403)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Thanks, I did not know the apps were discontinued.

Comment: Try the responsive and/or mobile sites in your phone’s browser. They work pretty well. I never liked the apps because their features were too limited, and now that they’re not being maintained, that’s even more reason to abandon them.

Comment: @CodyGray What are the URLs for those sites?

Comment: It's the same: https://stackoverflow.com and https://meta.stackoverflow.com. The UX designers have made the design more "responsive" recently, so when you browse to it on a phone, you should see it immediately. There's also a link in the footer to "Disable Responsiveness" or, conversely "Enable Responsiveness". If you want the mobile site, you can find that link in the footer, too. They're at the bottom of every page, in the far left column.